# Typescript Microsoft Graph Client - Suppress console error for 404 errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-404

I am using the [microsoft graph client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client) to attempt to fetch users profile pictures, however when the user does not have a profile picture this endpoint returns 404. I am catching the error thrown by the client as this is fine and we just want to continue without a picture if they have no picture:

```
const photoData: Blob = await this.client.api(fetchUrl)
                .get()
                .catch(() => { });
```

This works fine, however every 404 error results in the graph client printing the error to the console:
[image]

This isn't a massive deal but it can cause a lot of spam which is annoying when debugging, and we want to log client errors so we don't want to log things that aren't actually a problem.

Can I tell the graph client to not log this error somehow? Or is there a way to check if the user has a picture before trying to fetch it?

Comment: The error you show is 400 not 404, and 400 errors are usually a malformed request.  Is it supposed to be $value, or should that have been replaced with an actual value?

Comment: @James apologies, was just avoiding showing any real data in the picture so I put a dummy value but didnt notice that caused a 400 instead, updated the pic to the actual 404 error.

Comment: So I don't think you can hide 404s from the console.  If you had a server endpoint that could tell you if the picture existed before you tried to load it, that might work in this case.  You could also handle all requests that point to a non-existent picture by responding with an error, but you'd again need an endpoint that would check if the picture existed, serve it if so, and serve some other response if not.  All of my suggestions here need server code.